# Is it intended to lose WiFi connection after switching to monitor mode in Kali Linux?

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux

I am using a Realtek 8821AE internal card in a live Kali Linux. Every time I switch to monitor mode I lose my connection to WiFi.

Is this intended?

Note: I tested the card with aircrack suite and succeeded when trying the injection test.

Comment: This is not a security question but rather a question about networking.

Comment: sorry is there anything i should do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are connected to WiFi, your card runs in managed mode. That is required in order to talk to the access point. When you put your card in monitor mode, you are changing the way it treats signals from actively to passively, hence, you lose your connection.

You can get a TP Link WL722N USB adapter which has an Atheros chipset that works perfectly with Aircrack if you want to stay connected with your internal wifi card.